# Can't dismiss modal view when tap a button

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, modalviewcontroller

In "FirstViewController" I declare a button which present the modal view "InfoViewController".

In "InfoViewController", I declare a toolbar with a "modalViewButton" UIButton which dismiss the modal view. But the "OK" UIButton doesn't work. I don't know why.

Here's FirstViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "InfoViewController.h"

@interface FirstViewController : UIViewController 
{
    InfoViewController *infoViewController; 
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) InfoViewController *infoViewController;
@end
```

Here's FirstViewController.m

```
#import "FirstViewController.h"
@implementation FirstViewController
@synthesize infoViewController;

- (IBAction)modalViewAction:(id)sender
{  
    if (self.infoViewController == nil)
        self.infoViewController = [[[InfoViewController alloc] initWithNibName:
                                NSStringFromClass([InfoViewController class]) bundle:nil] autorelease];
    [self presentModalViewController:self.infoViewController animated:YES];
}

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [infoViewController  release];
    [super dealloc];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];   
}

#pragma mark - View lifecycle

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIButton* modalViewButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeInfoLight];
    [modalViewButton addTarget:self 
                    action:@selector(modalViewAction:) 
          forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    UIBarButtonItem *modalBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:modalViewButton];
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = modalBarButtonItem;
    [modalBarButtonItem release];
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

@end
```

Here's InfoViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>     
@interface InfoViewController : UIViewController 
{

}
-(IBAction)infoDismissAction:(id)sender;
@end
```

Here's the InfoViewController.m

```
#import "InfoViewController.h"

@implementation InfoViewController

- (IBAction)infoDismissAction:(id)sender
{
    [self.parentViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) 
    {

    }
    return self;
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [super dealloc];
}    

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

#pragma mark - View lifecycle

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UILabel *infoLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    infoLabel.frame = CGRectMake(50, 100, 100, 40);     
    infoLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;        
    infoLabel.text = @"About";      
    [self.view addSubview:infoLabel];       

    UIToolbar *toolBar;
    toolBar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 50)];
    toolBar.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 50);
    toolBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleDefault;
    [toolBar sizeToFit];    

    UIBarButtonItem *flexibleSpace = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:                               UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace 
                                                                                target:nil 
                                                                                        action:nil] autorelease];

    UIBarButtonItem *doneButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"OK" 
                                                                   style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered 
                                                              target:self 
                                                              action:@selector(infoDismissAction:)];

    UIBarButtonItem* infoTitle = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"About" 
                                                              style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain 
                                                             target:self action:nil];

    NSArray *barButtons = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:flexibleSpace,flexibleSpace,infoTitle,flexibleSpace,doneButton,nil];

    [toolBar setItems:barButtons];

    [self.view addSubview:toolBar]; 

    [toolBar release];
    [infoTitle release];
    [doneButton release];
    [barButtons release];
    [infoLabel release];
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

@end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would solve this issue with a delegate method.

First make a protocol in your modalViewController

```
@protocol ModalViewDelegate <NSObject>

 - (void)didDismissModalView;

@end
```

And set a delegate property in the same modalVC:

```
id<ModalViewDelegate> dismissDelegate;
```

Then make a buttonActionMethod that calls the delegate in the modalVC:

```
- (void)methodCalledByButton:(id)sender 
{
    // Call the delegate to dismiss the modal view
    [self.dismissDelegate didDismissModalView];
}
```

Now your modalVC is done you have to prepare the mainVC calling the modalVC:
You have to make your MainViewController comform to the delegate:

```
@interface MainViewController : UIViewController <ModalViewDelegate>
```

At the place you alloc your ModalViewController you have to set the delegate property you made in your modalViewController:

```
self.myModalViewController.dismissDelegate = self;
```

Now the MainViewController listens to the delegate and the only thing you need to do is implement the delegateMethod.

```
-(void)didDismissModalView
{
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Now your ModalVC will dismiss on a buttonpress (at least when you call the method properly)

Hope this all makes sense.
Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

You can only dismiss currently displayed modal view, so in your method `infoDismissAction:` you should do one of following

1) `[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];`

2) Send to `parent view controller` message that current modal view should be dismissed and send reference to that view.

Second approach is better as it is more safe.

Comment: Yep, that's a better answer. @lavitanien, if you want to see the 2nd suggestion in action, study the code in the "Utility" template that comes with Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

In your `-infoDismissAction` try to call `[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];`

Answer (score 0):

Here the best sample code for the model view for iphone and ipad also.

The popups have a number of configurable items. They can be animated to either slide or popup onto the display. Once visible, they can be dismissed either by tapping the screen or after a programmed delay. The background and text colors can also be adjusted however you like.

Download the [sample code from here.](https://github.com/chrismiles/CMPopTipView)

Answer (score 0):

The current answers are deprecated. Here is the updated code:

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
```