# How to call a method in the rootviewcontroller from a presented modal view controller at the time of dismissing the model view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, methods, uiviewcontroller

I have a main view controller which is shown when the app launches and it contains a tab bar with center raised button for image capture. i have presented a model view controller with UIimagepicker controller and after uploading the image i need to dismiss the model and call  the method of (UIimagepicker) in the main view controller

for that i wrote the code like this
.h file

```
ViewController *viewController;
@property (retain) ViewController *viewController;
```

.m file

```
    - (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{

    if(buttonIndex == 0)
    {

        [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
        [viewController btnTap];

        NSLog(@"uploaded");
    }
    else{
         [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    }

}
```

in viewcontroller .m

```
-(void)btnTap{

         [self.actForImage  showFromTabBar:tabBarController.tabBar];
        // act for image is the action sheet
        // this method will be called when click on the center button of tabbar
 }
```

I kept a break point and checked the -(void)btnTap method is not called.
Is there any other way to call the methods in the main view controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delegates are the answer!

What you need to do is setup a protocol in your ModalViewController. And instead of Dismissing it directly in your modalViewController you should dismiss it in the delegate method.

Check out this answer:

[Can't dismiss modal view when tap a button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7764347/cant-dismiss-modal-view-when-tap-a-button/7764511#7764511)

This is the way to dismiss the modalviewcontroller in the delegate class.
After you dismissed it in your ViewController class you can then call any other method you like.

EDIT:
The more extensive answer is written at the comments.

Comment: i have tried the the solution but it does not work for me. As i am also using navigation in the modelVC that presented. i want to dismiss the view at the last screen for that i am doing [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES]; but i think as per your answer only from the modelVC the delegate can be called

Comment: Well.. the VC that calls up the ModalVC could call up a single class that arranges the delegate and let that single class create your multiple views with your navigation on top of that. Every time you navigate you send a message to your controller class inside your ModalVC and when your done, instead of dismissing directly you send the controller a message and let him handle the delegate to the ViewController that called up the ModalVC. If you know what I mean..

Comment: This means you have a VC class which called the ModalVC. You have a Controller class that arranges the navigation inside the ModalVC. You have your multiple Views that are created from the Controller class and when they are done they send a message back to the Controller who then creates the next view needed. When you are at the last screen in your ModalVC ( OR when you want to dismiss your modalVC anyway) you send a message to your Controller class and tell him to dismiss the ModalVC in the way I described above.

Comment: It is too extensive to make in a short time. What you need to understand is that you need a MainController class that arranges both the dismissalDelegate and the view navigation on your screen. In such a way that you push and pop the views manually in that class. Also make a check if the last view is on screen or the cancel button is pressed so you can call the dismiss delegate method and the extra function you wanted.

Comment: Finally it worked, i have created the delegate methods and passed the control to the controller class and called the method i require. thanks for the help.